# How to replace array of object property name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I need to replace array of object in javascript. Here is my data variable and I want to update data variable

```
const data = [{name: "poran", id: "22"}];
```

Expected value:

```
data = [{value: "poran", age: "22"}];
```

How can I replace array of object?

Comment: To be clear: you cannot change a property name. You can add a new property and remove properties you don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new array with the use of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and some [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```js
const data = [{name:"poran",id:"22"}];

const result = data.map(({ name:value , id:age }) => ({value, age}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I first time see that syntax: `{ name:value , id:age }` - very nice +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `.forEach()` loop over the array:

```
data.forEach((obj) {
  obj.value = obj.name;
  obj.age = obj.id;
  delete obj.name;
  delete obj.id;
});
```

It's a little simpler if you just make a new array with `.map()`, but if you need to keep the old objects because there are lots of other properties, this would probably be a little less messy.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const data = [{name:"poran",id:"22"}]
const rst = data.map(res=>({value: res.name, age: res.id}));

console.log(rst)
```